# R: Restructuring a data.frame in order to plot lines correctly, lines() and points() solution

Tags: r, plot, dataframe, lines, points

My sample data.frame looks like this:

```
xy <- data.frame(NAME=c("NAME1","NAME1","NAME1","NAME2","NAME2","NAME2"),ID=c(87,87,87,199,199,199), SURVEY_YEAR=c(1986,1994,1999,1909,1924,1927), REFERENCE_YEAR=c(1984,1986,1984,1899,1909,1924), VALUE_SURVEY_YEAR=c(20,50,-15,-70,-80,-100),VALUE_REFERENCE_YEAR=c(75,25,-90,-8,-55,-10))

xy
       NAME  ID SURVEY_YEAR REFERENCE_YEAR VALUE_SURVEY_YEAR VALUE_REFERENCE_YEAR
1 NAME1  87        1986           1984                20                   75
2 NAME1  87        1994           1986                50                   25
3 NAME1  87        1999           1984               -15                  -90
4 NAME2 199        1909           1899               -70                   -8
5 NAME2 199        1924           1909               -80                  -55
6 NAME2 199        1927           1924              -100                  -10
```

I am looking for a way to generate single plots defined by group (based on the `ID`).

**Generally I am looking for a way to always plot row based points in this pattern**

**- starting point: `REFERENCE_YEAR/REFERENCE_YEAR_VALUE` to end point:
   `SURVEY_YEAR/SURVEY_YEAR_VALUE` and connect these points by a line**

In numbers the example for the group plot with ID 87 would be as follows

Points should be plotted in the following way:

- For row 1 plot a starting point 1984/75 and end point 1986/20 and
  these two points should be connected by a line
- Then move on to row 2 and plot starting point 1986/25 and end point
  1994/50 and connect the points with a line
- Then move on to row 3 and plot a starting point 1984/-90 and end
  point 1999/-15 and connect the points with a line.

As this group (defined by `ID`) is finished now, start with a new graph and repeat the whole procedure with a new plot and a new group (in this case for the group with `ID` 199).

**EDIT: WHAT I DID IN BASER SO FAR:**

I tried to reorganise the dataframe by writing `REFERENCE_YEAR` and `SURVEY_YEAR` one below the other and reorganised the data into two columns `YEAR` and `VALUE` in order to create an `xy plot` but this didn't result in correct plots as described above.

```
xy <- reshape(xy, direction="long",
              varying = list(c("SURVEY_YEAR","REFERENCE_YEAR"), c("VALUE_SURVEY_YEAR","VALUE_REFERENCE_YEAR")), 
              v.names=c("YEAR","VALUE"), times = c("SURVEY_YEAR", "REFERENCE_YEAR"))
xy <- xy[with(xy, order(NAME, ID, YEAR,time, id)), ]
```

After that I am splitting it by group (defined by `ID`) and I'm plotting it into separate graphs.

```
  ind <- split(x = xy,f = xy[,'ID'])
    plot1 <- function(x) {
      fname <- paste0(x[1, 'ID'], '.png')
      png(fname, width=1679, height=1165, res=150)
      par(mar=c(6,8,6,5))
      plot(x = c(1946, 2014),
           y = range(x$VALUE, na.rm=TRUE),
           type='n',
           main=x[1, 'NAME'])
      points(x[,c('YEAR','VALUE')], type="l", lwd=2)
      points(x[,c('YEAR','VALUE')], type="p", lwd=1, cex=0.7, pch=21, bg='white')
    dev.off()
    }
    plot2 <- function(x) {
      fname <- paste0(x[1, 'ID'], '.png')
      png(fname, width=1679, height=1165, res=150)    
      par(mar=c(6,8,6,5))
      plot(x[,c('YEAR','VALUE')],
           type='n',
           main=x[1, 'NAME'])
    points(x[,c('YEAR','VALUE')], type="l", lwd=2)
    points(x[,c('YEAR','VALUE')], type="p", lwd=1, cex=0.7, pch=21, bg='white')
    dev.off() 
    }

    lapply(ind, function(x) ifelse(any(x$YEAR < 1946 & x$YEAR < 2014), plot2(x), plot1(x)))
```

Does anyone have an idea how I could solve the above mentioned problem? A solution in baseR would be best!

Comment: Too complicated to dig thru.  Can you just state clearly which columns of data (and which subsets of rows) in your original dataframe should be plotted in each line?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I tried to break down the question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25920050/r-lines-and-points-solution-in-multiple-plots-separated-by-groups it would be great if you could have a look at it!

Comment: Are these two questions not exact duplicates of one another?  Am I missing something?

Comment: you are right @RichardScriven. It was requested that I would include everything into one question I am sorry. Thats why I deleted the other question (which was an attempt to make it shorter). But I would be happy about suggestions how I could solve this!

Comment: these kinds of plots tend to be easier in ggplot as a general rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick and dirty `ggplot` alternative using the original data:

```
# create a grouping variable to be able to separate adjacent lines within each ID
xy$grp <- factor(ave(xy$ID, xy$ID, FUN = seq_along))

# plot
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = xy, aes(x = REFERENCE_YEAR,
                      xend =  SURVEY_YEAR,
                      y = VALUE_REFERENCE_YEAR,
                      yend = VALUE_SURVEY_YEAR,
                      colour = grp)) +
  geom_segment() +
  facet_wrap(~ ID, scales = "free_x") +
  xlab("Year") +
  ylab("Value") +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

Comment: this is great, thanks @Henrik! but since I have done everything in baseR can you also think of a solution in baseR?

Comment: @redshoe, Sorry, I can't help you with that right now. Let's hope someone else is keen to answer!

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like this?

```
x = c(xy$SURVEY_YEAR,xy$REFERENCE_YEAR)
y = c(xy$VALUE_SURVEY_YEAR, xy$VALUE_REFERENCE_YEAR)
tab = cbind(x,y)

plot(tab[,1], tab[,2])
for (i in 1:nrow(xy)) {
lines(c(xy$SURVEY_YEAR[i],xy$REFERENCE_YEAR[i]), c(xy$VALUE_SURVEY_YEAR[i], xy$VALUE_REFERENCE_YEAR[i]))
}
```

Comment: the problem with this is that it would plot everything into one plot and not into groups (as defined by `ID`)